# How is event variable being used to invoke a method getServletContext without declaring an object of ServletContextEvent class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, servlets, servlet-listeners

In a class

```
class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener //line 1
{         
         public void contextInitialised(ServletContextEvent event){
              ServletContext sc = event.getServletContext(); //line 2
              //other functionalities
         }
}
```

I want to ask in "line 2" how is event variable being used to invoke a method getServletContext without declaring an object of ServletContextEvent class? Here `ServletContextEvent event = new ServletContextEvent();` is not being done here. Can we do so for any general classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a class that is instantiated and executed by servlet runtime (tomcat/jetty). Its part of the Servlet API Specificate. You can read about this here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm

Creation of ServletContextEvent object is taken care by the servlet runtime. And it passes that object in the invocation of the method.